# Notifying when React state is set?

Tags: ajax, forms, reactjs

Just can't think of a way to do this: I have a form and make an ajax request with the input upon submission, but how do I ensure that the state is completely set before I make the request? I know that setState is asynchronous and a version that accepts a callback exists, but I don't want to submit as soon as the state is set, rather when the user clicks the submit button. When I make the request, this.state is null still.

Any help or tips would be appreciated, thank you!

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Landing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      question: ""
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhttp.status === 200) {
          console.log("success")
        } else {
          alert('There was a problem with the request.');
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open('POST', '/save', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ question: this.state.question }));
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ question: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="landing">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
          <label>
            Question:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.question} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>    
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
  this.setState({
        state : newState
    },
    () => {
       // Call some method when state changes were done.
    });
```

Also you should use `e.preventDefault();` as you are not submitting the for to any server.

```
  handleClick(e) {

   e.preventDefault();
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhttp.status === 200) {
          console.log("success")
        } else {
          alert('There was a problem with the request.');
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open('POST', '/save', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ question: this.state.question }));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there any way to delay the method call until a button has been pressed/some action, instead of calling it as soon as the state finishes changing?

Comment: You are doing it right. In `handleClick` you should send `ajax` request and based on the response received set the state again with new data.

Comment: What do you mean "based on the response received set the state again with new data?" I send the value of this.state.question with the POST request, and I'm not expecting to update it afterwards.

Comment: Do you want to get notified of the response received? Whether your request was successful or not !

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I don't want to make the request until the state is finished setting, otherwise it would be sending wrong information. I think I found a workaround though by using a flag and delaying until it's true. Thank you!